# How do I make plants interact with the environment?

Tags: particles, physics, collision

Vague, I know, but what I'm essentially trying to crack is: You know how if you have a plant on a desk against a wall or a bush that grows enough that the leaves start pushing against walls and other objects, the leaves and even the branches will fold/bend on contact. Essentially the plant will be pushed up against the wall. I'm trying to make that happen without running a whole simulation and I can't seem to find any research or tutorials on this. Maybe there's a way with Geometry Nodes? Or some collisions trick I'm not seeing?

If anyone has an answer please help

Comment: Is it not enough to just use proportional editing?

Comment: can't it be a cylinder that follows a curve with Array + Curve modifier?